# Error in 'exec': double free or corruption (fasttop) : 0x00000000021a2c80

Tags: c

I am trying to build a program using switch to manipulate linked lists of characters, but I get this error:

```
  *** Error in `exec': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000021a2c80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
[0x40a467]
[0x40fcf2]
[0x41050e]
[0x400c20]
[0x400e8f]
[0x401123]
[0x4013ae]
[0x4009ba]
```

I know that this error is something about the allocation and deallocation but I have literally checked the code for more than 3 hrs and I cannot see the mistake, can any of you who are professionals help me or guide me to find the error?

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
    struct list *prev;
    char info;
    struct list *next;
};

struct list* push_front(struct list *my_list, char value )
{
        struct list *newel;
        newel = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        if (newel == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        newel->info = value;
        newel->next = my_list;
        newel -> prev = NULL;
        if (my_list!=NULL)
        {
            my_list -> prev = newel;
        }
        return newel;

}

struct list* remove_elem(struct list *my_list, char value)
{
    struct list *cursor , *nex, *prv;
    int x = 0;
    cursor = my_list;
    if (cursor==NULL)
    {
        printf("The element is not in the list!\n");
        return my_list;
    }
    else if (cursor->next==NULL)
    {
        if (value==cursor->info)
        return NULL;
        else
        {
        printf("The element is not in the list!\n");
        return my_list;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (cursor->next!=NULL)
        {
            if (cursor->info==value)
            {
                if (cursor->prev==NULL)
                {
                    cursor=cursor->next;
                    free(cursor->prev);
                    cursor->prev=NULL;
                    my_list=cursor;
                }
                else
                {
                    nex=cursor->next;
                    prv=cursor->prev;
                    prv->next=nex;
                    nex->prev=prv;
                    free(cursor);
                }
                    x=1;
            }
            else
            cursor=cursor->next;
        }
        if (cursor->info==value)
        {
            if (cursor->prev!=NULL)
            {
                cursor->prev->next=NULL;
                free(cursor);
                x=1;
            }
            else
            {
                x=1;
                cursor=NULL;
                my_list=NULL;
            }
        }
        if (x==1)
        return my_list;
        else
        {
            printf("The element is not in the list!\n");
            return my_list;
        }
    }
}

void print(struct list *my_list)
{
    struct list *ptr;
    ptr = my_list;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", ptr->info);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void rev(struct list *my_list)
{
    struct list *ptr;
    ptr = my_list;
    if (ptr!=NULL)
    {
        while (ptr -> next != NULL)
        ptr = ptr -> next;
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            printf("%c ",ptr -> info);
            ptr = ptr -> prev;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct list *dispose_list(struct list* my_list)
{
   struct list *removedList;
   struct list *returnlist;
   if (my_list == NULL)
   {
        return 0;
   }else
   {
       removedList = my_list->next;
        my_list = removedList;
        returnlist = my_list;
   }


   return returnlist;
}


char readChar()
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }while (c == ' ' || c == '\n');
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    struct list* new_list = NULL;
    int nr;
    char ch;
    while (nr != 5)
    {
        scanf("%d", &nr);
        switch (nr)
        {
            case 1:
                ch = readChar();
                new_list = push_front(new_list, ch);
                break;
            case 2:
                ch = readChar();
                new_list = remove_elem(new_list, ch);
                break;

            case 3:
                print(new_list);
                //printf("\n");
                break;

            case 4:
                rev(new_list);
                //printf("\n");
                break;

            case 5:

                exit(1);
                break;
        }
    }
    dispose_list(new_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the whole error.

Comment: This is not an [mcve]. When exactly does the error happen?

Comment: In your else branch, you `free(cursor);`. After that, you go back to the loop condition with the value of `cursor` unchanged. Unless the memory pointed to by `cursor` was either reallocated or unmapped, you're just gonna go into the else branch over and over...

Comment: Every time I see linked list code, I am thankful that we have versions already done for us so that we need not debug yet another linked list.

Comment: do you want to remove all nodes with `node->info == value` or just the first one you encounter?

Comment: @Pablo All of them

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go through the list and check if the current node's info is the same as the
value. If that's the case, remove the node, update the `prev` and `next`
pointers around the current node, free the node and move to the next one. Stop
when `NULL` has reached. If the current's node `prev` is `NULL`, then we have to
update the `head` as well by setting `my_list`. The function returns the new
head of the list or `NULL` when the list is empty or when all nodes of the list
were removed. This is my version:

```
struct list* remove_elem(struct list *my_list, char value)
{
    int removed_something = 0;

    struct list *current = my_list, *tofree;

    while(current)
    {
        if(current->info == value)
        {
            if(current->next)
                current->next->prev = current->prev;

            if(current->prev)
                current->prev->next = current->next;
            else
                my_list = current->next; // update head of list

            tofree = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(tofree);
            removed_something = 1;
        } else
            current = current->next;
    }

    if(removed_something == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Node with value '%c' not found\n", value);

    return my_list;
}
```

I don't do `while(current->next)` because at the end of the loop I would have to
repeat the code in the loop for the last element of the list. By using
`while(element)` I reach **all** elements of the list inside the loop and don't
have to repeat the removing code after the loop, which is causing you trouble.

I also don't understand what your `dispose_list` function does. You are just
removing the head but you are not freeing the head and you are returing the rest
of the list. You also are not updating the `prev` pointer of the new head. This
seems all strange to me. If you want to dispose of the head:

```
struct list *dispose_list(struct list* my_list)
{
    if(my_list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    struct list *oldhead = my_list;

    my_list = my_list->next;
    if(my_list)
        my_list->prev = NULL;

    free(oldhead);

    return my_list;
}
```

And if you want to free the whole list:

```
void free_list(struct list *my_list)
{
    if(my_list == NULL)
        return;

    struct list *tmp;

    while(my_list)
    {
        tmp = my_list;
        my_list = my_list->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```